# Python timedate match

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, datetime

I have a function that I call which generates a timestamp on a event that comes through a For loop.

**Function, and RAW timestamp**

```
def atimer ():
        timenow = time.time()
        return(timenow)

print timenow
1434615010.27858
```

The timestamp looks like this "1434615010.27858", which is nice and small for database use in sqlite3. When I convert the timestamp using datetime I get a proper statement of time(see below)..

**Converted**

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1434615010.27858)
2015-06-18 10:10:10.278580
```

The issue with this extremely efficient problem is that I have a influx of events that show up as the below timestamp printout.

```
2015-06-18 11:36:57.830000
2015-06-18 11:36:57.830000
2015-06-18 11:36:57.830000
2015-06-18 11:36:59.340000
2015-06-18 11:36:59.340000
2015-06-18 11:36:59.340000
2015-06-18 11:37:00.740000
2015-06-18 11:37:00.740000
2015-06-18 11:37:00.740000
2015-06-18 11:37:02.130000
```

I would like to compare the timestamps with each other and then only submit the first one in that given minute to the database (SQL UPDATE).

**Question>** Is Regex my only option here or can I tone this timestamp itself down to not give me such a detailed timestamp?

**Info:** The main reason I have chosen this timestamp was that it's small and takes up less space in the DB, especially when you work with 1000's of them.

**Below is the output I'm trying to get at...**

```
2015-06-18 11:36
2015-06-18 11:37
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just add the dates every time you find a new minute? The times are in order yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put them into a dict, that way you'll only get one entry per every minute:

```
times = [
    '2015-06-18 11:36:57.830000',
    '2015-06-18 11:36:57.830000',
    '2015-06-18 11:36:59.340000',
    '2015-06-18 11:36:59.340000',
    ]

time_dict = {}

for time in times:
    time_dict[(time.split('.'))[0][:-3]] = 1

print(time_dict.keys())
```

Even better, you could create the dict before you translate the date. That way you only have to do the conversion once per same entry:

```
times = [
    '1434615010.27858',
    '1434615010.27858',
    ]

time_dict = {}

for time in times:
    time_dict[time] = 1

for time in time_dict.keys():
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(time))
    print((str(date).split('.')[0])[:-3])
```

Comment: Thanks stevieb. Makes a lot more sense.

Comment: You're welcome. I fixed the code so it works only on HH:MM per your original question, instead of HH:MM:SS as I had in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove seconds and microseconds from each date to get the output you want:

```
import datetime

aDate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1434615010.27858)

print aDate

aDate -= datetime.timedelta(seconds=aDate.second, microseconds=aDate.microsecond)

print aDate
```

This prints:

```
2015-06-18 05:10:10.278580
2015-06-18 05:10:00
```

Comment: why do you add a "-" infront of the = ?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to remember what the last thing you printed was, and only print out again if the new one is different:

```
lastTime = None
while True:
    thisTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(atimer()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    if thisTime != lastTime:
        print thisTime
        lastTime = thisTime
```